# Why does this throw an AssertionError?

Tags: python

I am solving a problem for a university, in which I need to display a dictionary that consists of: 1) keys - names of characters; 2) values - number of characters in replicas of these characters.

The answer is correct, but throws AssertionError:

```
test_data = [
    ("", "{'#Bahram: 188', '#Zilziela: 415', '#Masha: 221'}")
]

for inp, out in test_data:
    with Tester([inp]) as t:
        c31()
        assert len(t) == 1, 'Incorrect answer'
        assert t[0] == out+'\n', 'Incorrect answer'
```

There is my solution:

```
def c31():
    with open('dialogs.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        arr = f.readlines()
        
        result_dict = {}
        
        for sentence in arr:
            if sentence.startswith('#'):
                author = sentence.split(':')[0] + ':'
                chars = len(sentence[len(author):-1].rstrip())
                if author in result_dict:
                    result_dict[author] += chars
                else:
                    result_dict[author] = chars
        return result_dict
```

Also, down below is the text, located at the 'dialogs.txt'

```
#Bahram: Can you count? 
#Zilziela: I do. One, two, three, four, seventeen, twenty...right?
#Bahram: Yeah... Can you write?
#Zilziela: I haven't tried to write.
#Bahram: And don't try!

#Bahram: Can you count and write?
#Masha: I can.
#Bahram: What's five-five?
#Masha: Twenty-five! 
#Zilziela: Master, that's a big scientist, eh!

#Bahram: I'm your mother, I'm your father, and of course your grandfather.
#Zilziela: Look, I'll be a grandmother! Grandma Zilziela!

#Zilziela: There's a wonderful creation, with a rope on the back and a hanger on the head!

#Masha: Tell me, Zilziela, have you been on vacation?
#Zilziela: What is it?
#Masha: Everyone has to take a month off every year! How long have you been working?
#Zilziela: A thousand years!
#Masha: Oh, so you're entitled to... 83 years of vacation.
#Zilziela: Okay! That's it, I'm going on vacation!
#Bahram: I'll show you "vacation"!

#Zilziela: I can see well in the dark...[boom]
#Masha: Oh, what's that, Zilziela?
#Zilziela: Don't be frightened, Masha, it's me, Zilziela, I bumped my head.
```

Thank you!